# Need to pass build fail notification of Git committer whenever a Jenkins build is triggered

Tags: git, jenkins

So am trying to have a pipeline(GIT commit triggers CI pipeline) notification using Jenkinsfile where am catching the exception for the person who gets notified when a build fails in Jenkins.

```
catch (err) {
        currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
            mail body: "project build error is here: ${env.BUILD_URL}" ,
            from: 'xxxx@yyyy.com',
            replyTo: 'yyyy@yyyy.com',
            subject: 'project build failed',
            to: "some@jdkjf.com"
        throw err
    }
```

in the **to** field i want to pass dynamic GIT user ID(EMail). whoever causes the build to fail should be notified.
How do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a generic parameter for the to field , **${env.To}**

and make sure you create this value  with loadproperties

```
sh '''
    echo To=$(get you commiter email) >> propsfile.txt
'''

script {
           properties = readProperties file: 'propsfile.txt'
           properties.each{ k, v -> env."${k}"="${v}" }  
       }
```

Comment: So it will read from a list of key, value email address from propsfile.txt?

Comment: yes it will create env variables so you can use it later